# Canonical Apprenticeships?

Tags: community, canonical

I am currently a student doing my 4th year at college passing 3 separate courses, My issue is that when I finish my course I will need to get a job or some sort of way to get income, I was thinking on going into freelance website design but that is a different story, I love Ubuntu and I love the design and purpose of it, I was wondering if Canonical does some sort of apprenticeships ? I am sure if I had that on my CV it would make my job hunting much more easier. Experience is my only downfall right now considering I have the qualifications having something like that on my job application would lead to better and more fulfilling jobs,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for Canonical but in the wider Ubuntu community, there are many projects that are part of Ubuntu which fall into [Google's Summer of Code](https://developers.google.com/open-source/soc/).

Essentially, Google sponsors open source projects to hire students over summer. It's not a small amount of money either but it lacks some of the formal structure that you might be looking for. I can't say whether or not that sort of experience  will directly help but it would certainly make you a better developer.

If you want to go and work at Canonical HQ, I guess the best way to find out is to contact them and ask. [Their new website](http://www.canonical.com/about) isn't that handy for finding HR contact details, but their main switchboard number is +442076302400. Give it a shot. The worst that can happen is they say no.

Otherwise, [there are actual job vacancies at Canonical](http://www.canonical.com/careers). Again, I can't speak for Canonical but they might be willing to take on junior devs. Worth a shot.